# Get URL Query parameters GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I need to get "query parameters" from this URL with GWT:

```
127.0.0.1:8888/App.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#Login&oauth_token=theOauthToken&oauth_verifier=123456
```

I need to get the `oauth_verifier`

However, `Window.Location.getParameter("oauth_verifier");` is returning `null`.

How to get this?

Comment: Your URL is probably broken: The fragment must appear after the query, so it should look like `127.0.0.1:8888/App.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&oauth_token=theOauthToken&oauth_verifier=123456#Login`
 (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax)

Comment: This is will for a callback from oauth sign-in, so the URL has to be built before, as these query params "&oauth_token=theOauthToken&oa‌​uth_verifier=123456" will be appended in the tail. I mean, I need the GWT to handle the parsing of the oauth_verifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this using [getHash()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html):-

```
string s= Window.Location.getHash();
```

Comment: Window.Location.getHash() with no args